# The DbContext of type cannot be pooled

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a ReadOnlyDBContext to my application in .Net Core 3.1 and I am getting this runtime error:

> The DbContext of type 'ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext' cannot be pooled
> because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a
> single parameter of type DbContextOptions.

Here is my `ApplicationDbContext` which is working fine when pooled:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
    ...
}
```

Then I added a `ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { 
       this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }
}
```

And in the Startup.cs:

```
// Add database Context
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Database.Url);
});
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository), typeof(EFRepository<ApplicationDbContext>));

// Add read only database Context
services.AddDbContextPool<ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Database.ReadOnlyUrl);
});
services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository), typeof(ReadOnlyEFRepository<ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext>));
```

Comment: What if you use non-generic `DbContextOptions` in both constructors?

Comment: @Evk I tried using DbContextOptions<DbContext> options in both but now it crashed with same error for ApplicationDbContext too

Comment: But I mean just DbContextOptions, non-generic, not DbContextOptions<DbContext> (there is non-generic base class from which generic one inherits)

Comment: @Evk I now tried  DbContextOptions options and it worked. Can you post this as an answer and maybe some explanation of why it worked and is it safe to use it this way.

Comment: Cannot write an answer now, maybe tomorrow. I'm pretty sure it is safe. You are not calling those constructors directly, and when EF calls them - DbContextOptions is parent class of generic options, so any DbContextOption<Whatever> can be passed there, don't see any reason to use generic version in this case. Also it seems EF expects this for pooling (or maybe it wants either this or DbContextOptions<ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext>, because with your current setup, EF cannot pass DbContextOptions<ReadOnlyApplicationDbContext> to your constructor.